# Вывод reCaptcha в приложение

Tags: php, dom

Моё приложение работает с сайтом, при необходимости загрузить некоторую информацию приходится проходить проверку на стороне сайта - решить рекапчу.
 Сам сайт, содержит много банеров и видео, его загрузка занимает много времени.
Прошу вас помочь или высказать свои идеи. Как реализовать вывод рекапчи в приложение или может быть есть способ сделать отдельную страницу php? 
 Код прилагать думаю пока что незачем.

Comment: @Harry, что тут кому не понятно?

Comment: @Qwertiy я убрал метку C++, по-моему, она тут в полной мере ни при чем...

Comment: @Harry, я по 3 голоса за закрытие.

Comment: @Qwertiy А я тут при чем? Моего голоса там нет...

Comment: @Harry, это хорошо. Просто больше позвать было некого :)

Answer (score 0):

Рекапча отдаётся в iframe'е. Её можно вынуть, отобразить пользователю (в контреле WebBrowser) и когда он её отправит, обработать результат и подставить возвращённый токен в форму сайта, который ты парсишь.

Comment: Это известно...

Comment: @Zavet, а что не известно?

Comment: Достаточно попробовать ведь, чтобы понять в чём сложность. 
 Вот http://zavet-soft.ru/re/12.html
Нужно добиться того, чтобы в WebBrowser эта рекапча открылась, чтобы небыло ошибки Домена, нужно открыть рекапчу на нужном домене. Чтобы сделать это, я использовал JS функцию document.write , которая без проблем работат через обычный браузер и совсем не загружает фрейм от рекапчи в WebBrowser.
 В этом проблема...

Comment: @Zavet, не надо никаких write'ов. Просто открывай iframe непосредственно  капчой.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, можно чуть чуть подробнее, фрейм вставлять вместе с ссылкой приходится, чтобы он загрузился вообще и показался, ссылка в этом фрейме кажется динамической. Как это обработать?

Comment: Я отследил что меняется в ссылке на фрейм только её окончание &cb=oqcvcjfcse9e" например, по сниферу не могу найти откуда взять.

Comment: В общем очердной форум тролей и тем кому пофиг вообще. Очередной русский.
 Решение нашёл.